# Is it possible to have time-varying covariates and coefficients?

Tags: survival, cox-model

In an extended Cox model, the model accounts for time-varying covariates, that is, there are multiple points of observation for each respondent at various times.

Although the model now accounts for time, I've read that it is still important to check for PH in this time dependent model. When I do this, I still have some terms that violate PH. In this case, I can create an interaction between such covariates with time, which resolves the PH issue, but I'm not sure how this should be interpreted, as now I simultaneously have time-varying coefficients and time-varying covariates.